# Webdriver IO - Error: Command "printPage" is not yet implemented

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-io

Unable to use `printPage` and I also get the same error for `savePDF`

```
await browser.url('https://stackoverflow.com/')
await browser.printPage()
```

Results in:

```
Error: Command "printPage" is not yet implemented
    at Browser.retries (D:\Code\Repositories\auto-browse\node_modules\devtools\build\devtoolsdriver.js:90:34)
    at Browser.wrapCommandFn (D:\Code\Repositories\auto-browse\node_modules\@wdio\utils\build\shim.js:131:38)
    at Browser.<anonymous> (D:\Code\Repositories\auto-browse\node_modules\@wdio\utils\build\shim.js:270:24)
    at makePuzzle (D:\Code\Repositories\auto-browse\index.js:153:19)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async D:\Code\Repositories\auto-browse\index.js:183:5
```

package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.15.8",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.8",
        "@babel/register": "^7.15.3",
        "@wdio/cli": "^7.16.2",
        "@wdio/local-runner": "^7.16.2",
        "@wdio/mocha-framework": "^7.16.1",
        "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^7.16.1",
        "chromedriver": "^95.0.0",
        "wdio-chromedriver-service": "^7.2.2"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@wdio/selenium-standalone-service": "^7.16.3",
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "xlsx": "^0.17.3"
    }
```

Any ideas? I thought it might have been because Chrome is on version 95xxxx and chromedriver was on 94xxx but I sill get the same issue after deleting Node Modules and reinstalling with the above dependencies.